# Download coordinates (x, y) of a tracked point

Tags: after-effects, motion

I've gotten to where I can track my object and see it's coordinates using [this resource](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21695/get-location-x-y-of-motion-tracking-object).
I wanted to extract the location data for programming, but because I'm new to after effects, I'm not sure if I can or how I can extract it.

Comment: When you say programming - do you mean you want to reuse this data inside After Effects using After Effects "Expression" scripting, or export it somewhere else to use the data?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have tracked the position of the object on screen, you can copy the Feature Centre keyframes as shown in the screen grab below.

The coordinates relative to the comp will be available from the clipboard, which you can paste into any text editor (see screenshot using TextEdit on the Mac)

[image: grab]